# Weird error when accessing pandas column value by attribute (dot) vs bracket

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am having trouble with a really strange error in Python when it comes to accessing a value in a pandas dataframe.

For a given row and a specific column, the two code lines below return different values, when I expected them to be the same:

1. ```
   >> df[df.obsId == 107099]['length'].values[0]
   101.720001220703
   ```
2. ```
   >> df[df.obsId == 107099].length.values[0]
   101.64261358425581
   ```

I really don't understand why the length values returned are different. Aren't bracket access and attribute access supposed to be equivalent ? I thought it could be a float imprecision reason but the difference is actually big.

Also it might be useful to mention that when I display the dataframe, the corresponding value is 101.720001, which seems to indicate that the display accesses to the data with the first method rather than the second one:

[image: screenshot]

Any clue of what could be the reason of such an important difference, how to avoid it and which of the two methods to trust?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: dot notation is generally not recommended as methods share the same nomenclature. for example if you had a dataframe with a column called sum, df.sum will not return the column rather a sum of the series.I'm not sure of the error above but I suspect it's related. in short, stick to bracket notation.

Comment: Sadly I couldn't reproduce the error but you can have a look at the warnings for [Attribute access](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#attribute-access)

Comment: To add to the above, the `.` notation becomes problematic if you had previously used it to set a DataFrame attribute, which is **not** advisable. For instance if you do `df = pd.DataFrame(); df.length=2; df['length'] = [1,3,5,7]` `df.length` will (perhaps surprisingly) return 2. If you ever used `df. =` in your code, you should replace it with the bracket notation.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the hint of the comments, I finally understood the problem.

My data type was actually a geodataframe, and geodataframes appear to have a `.length` attribute. So the attribute notation referenced to this `.length` attribute instead of referencing to the identically named column, which happen to have different values!